# Post form method with already existing post in page

Tags: php, forms, post, methods, jcrop

I have a post method in my php page that is called once the page is created. Now I have a form on this same page and when you click it it should "refresh" the page with an image that is cropped. I get weird text on my screen when I run this:

First post method:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if($_FILES['afbeelding']['error'] == 0) {
    $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name']);
    if(filesize($_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name']) > 204800) {?> <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Maximale bestandsgrootte: 200KB"); window.location = "/inside.php"</script> <?php }
    else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $_FILES['afbeelding']['name']);}
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="?action=showCrop">
        <input type="hidden" name="x" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="y" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="images/<?php echo $_FILES['afbeelding']['name']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Verklein afbeelding!" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    echo '<img src="getimage.php?file=images/' . $_FILES['afbeelding']['name'] . '">';
```

And the method that should be called after submitting the form:

```
function showCrop(){
$targ_w = $_POST['w'];
$targ_h = $_POST['h'];
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = $_POST['image'];
$ext = end(explode(".", $_POST['image']));
switch($ext)
{
  case 'jpg';
  $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

  imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
  $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

  //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
  exit;
  break;
  case 'png';
  $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
  $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

  imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
  $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

  //header('Content-type: image/png');
  imagepng($dst_r,null,8);
  exit;
  break;
```

}
}

Comment: What kind of example?

Comment: a live example of the issue, i had a couple of issues with jcrop and it took me a while to sort mine but mine was multiple issues with binding after the ajax sent back the resulting image.

Comment: This is more an issue related to the POST than the JCrop I think.

Comment: what text appears when it refreshes?